# Why this code produce 1?

Tags: c++

Why this code produce 1? Someone, describe it for me pls.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;

  if (x++&&y++){
    y += 2;
  }
  cout << x + y << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Comment: Remember that the boolean operators uses *short-circuit evaluation*. And that the post-increment operators return the *original* value (before increment). And that zero is equal to `false`.

Answer (score 7):

- Initially x and y are 0
- Therefore x++ evaluates to false, and the second operand of && is never evaluated. x++ does increment x to 1. Since the condition is false, the conditional branch is not entered.
- x + y is 1 + 0 which equals 1

Answer (score 2):

user2079303 explains nicely (+1 by me already), as extension, I'll go a little more into detail:

`if(x++)` evaluates the value of x *before* the incrementation, so this little piece of code is equivalent to the following (need to buffer the old value!):

```cpp
int tmp = x;
x++;
if(tmp)
```

Be aware that within `c && cc`, the second condition `cc` is not evaluated any more if `c` is already false! So `if(x && y)` is equivalent to

```cpp
if(x)
{
    if(y)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Putting all this together, your code is equivalent to this variant, where I separated the if clause into code lines each one containing only one single instruction:

```cpp
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

int tmp = x;
x++;
if(tmp)
{
   tmp = y;
   y++;
   if(tmp)
       y += 2;
}
```

Suppose, your output now is quite obvious...